# Should methods in an API that return Task end with Task or Async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, naming-conventions

If an API has a synchronous method `T DoSomething<T>();`, what is the naming convention for the corresponding asynchronous method if it returns `Task<T>`?

```
Task<T> DoSomethingTask<T>();
```

or

```
Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>();
```

or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've seen in C# 5 / .NET 4.5, the preferred name is `DoSomethingTaskAsync` or `DoSomethingAsync`

For example, the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in .NET 4.5 has methods like `DownloadFileTaskAsync`, because it already had a method named `DownloadFileAsync`, so I assume the use of `TaskAsync` over `Async` is to maintain backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about an `async` or `await` method, then from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> By convention, the suffix "Async" is added to the names of methods
>   that are modified by the Async or async modifier.
>
> ...
>
> Exceptions to the convention can be made where an event, base class,
>   or interface contract suggests a different name. For example, the
>   names of common event handlers, such as button1_Click, are best not
>   renamed.